# Application crashes in nvcuda.dll after running for a long time

Tags: cuda

I have a strange issue when my application crashes in nvcuda.dll after running for about 2 hours. After spending a lot of time trying to debug the issue, I think I have an idea what’s going on but I’d like to know if anybody else has seen this problem.

My application launches most of its kernels in non-default streams and this process can go on for hours before there is a need to use default stream. Everything was working fine until I upgraded the drivers from some 320 version to most recent 332.50 (for K40m) version. What happens now is if the app runs for about 2 hours and then makes any call which uses default stream then it crashes during the call somewhere inside nvcuda.dll. At first I thought something is wrong with my kernels but it happens even if I use some basic stuff like cudaMemcpy (which uses default stream). The crash does not happen when the app is running for, say, 1 hour or 1.5 hours. It took me a while to realize that might be an issue with the driver so I uninstalled the new driver and installed the old one (320.92) and the problem was gone! I repeated the same process (changing the driver, rebooting then running the app again) multiple times and had 100% repro.

Unfortunately, I don’t have a small, self-contained repro but before I try to create one, has anybody seen something like that recently? The entry from Event Viewer at the time of the crash does not say much:

```
Faulting application name: <app>.exe, version: <version>, time stamp: 0x5316a970
Faulting module name: nvcuda.dll, version: 8.17.13.3250, time stamp: 0x52e1fa40
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000002226e7
Faulting process id: 0x1558
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf3831a2f3b71b
Faulting application path: <app>.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\nvcuda.dll
Report Id: aceb9a51-a433-11e3-9403-90b11c4725be
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Update 1**: 
I now have a simple application which reproduces the crash both on K20m and K40m cards. 
**Update 2**: 
Updated sample app, was able to repro the crash. From the call stack it looks like there is a stack overflow somewhere in nvcuda.dll.

Steps:

1. Install latest version (332.50) of the drivers on the machine.
2. In Visual Studio 2012 create a new CUDA 5.5 project.
3. Replace the contents of the kernel.cu with the code below.
4. Compile and run the code on the machine with K20m or K40m.
5. After approximately 2 hours of execution the app will crash and the entry below will be written into event log.
6. Uninstall the driver and install previous (e.g. 321.10) version of the driver.
7. Run the app, it should still be running after 2, 3 and more hours.

Log:

```
Faulting application name: CudaTests60.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5317974f
Faulting module name: nvcuda.dll, version: 8.17.13.3250, time stamp: 0x52e1fa40
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000004f5cb
Faulting process id: 0x23d0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf38ba16961e74
Faulting application path: d:\bin\test\CudaTests60.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\system32\nvcuda.dll
Report Id: 192506c4-a4be-11e3-9401-90b11c4b02c0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    {
        int crow = 10000;
        int ccol = 10000;
        int cshared = 10000;
        int xLength = crow * cshared;
        int yLength = cshared * ccol;
        int matLength = crow * ccol;

        thrust::device_vector<float> x(xLength);
        thrust::device_vector<float> y(yLength);
        thrust::device_vector<float> mat(matLength);

        thrust::fill(x.begin(), x.end(), 1.0f);
        thrust::fill(y.begin(), y.end(), 1.0f);
        thrust::fill(mat.begin(), mat.end(), .0f);

        cudaStream_t ops;
        cudaStatus = cudaStreamCreate(&ops);
        assert(0 == cudaStatus);

        cublasHandle_t cbh;
        cublasStatus_t cbstatus;
        cbstatus = cublasCreate(&cbh);
        assert(0 == cbstatus);

        cbstatus = cublasSetStream(cbh, ops);
        assert(0 == cbstatus);

        float alpha = 1;
        float beta = 0;
        float* px = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(x.data());
        float* py = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(y.data());
        float* pmat = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(mat.data());
        ULONGLONG start = GetTickCount64();
        ULONGLONG iter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            cbstatus = cublasSgemm(cbh, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, crow, ccol, cshared, &alpha, px, crow, py, cshared, &beta, pmat, crow);
            assert(0 == cbstatus);
            if (0 != cbstatus)
            {
                printf("cublasSgemm failed: %d.\n", cbstatus);
                break;
            }
            cudaStatus = cudaStreamSynchronize(ops);
            assert(0 == cudaStatus);
            if (0 != cudaStatus)
            {
                printf("cudaStreamSynchronize failed: %d.\n", cudaStatus);
                break;
            }

            ULONGLONG cur = GetTickCount64();
            // Exit after 2 hours.
            if (cur - start > 2 * 3600 * 1000)
                break;
            iter++;
        }

        // Crash will happen here.
        printf("Before cudaMemcpy.\n");
        float res = 0;
        cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(&res, px, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        assert(0 == cudaStatus);
        if (0 == cudaStatus)
            printf("After cudaMemcpy: %f\n", res);
        else
            printf("cudaMemcpy failed: %d\n", cudaStatus);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been fixed in Tesla drivers starting version 333.11. If you have the same problem, make sure you've updated the drivers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised the program crashes right where you've indicated.
This line of code is illegal:

```
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(pmat, px, x.size() * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

both `pmat` and `px` are pointers to device memory.  However you've requested `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` which means the `pmat` pointer is interpreted as a host pointer and gets dereferenced during the copy operation.  Dereferencing a device pointer in host code is illegal and will cause a seg fault.

With suitable modifications I ran your code on linux and it indicates a seg fault at that line.

Note that I'm not disputing there may be a problem in the driver you indicated (bugs are possible!), but I don't think this code is reproducing anything related to a driver bug.

Bugs can be filed at:  https://developer.nvidia.com/nvbugs/cuda/add You will need to log in with developer credentials.

As an aside, your code appears to take a designed exit after 2 hours.  I don't see how it could be running longer as you've indicated:

> - 7.Run the app, it should still be running after 2, 3 and more hours.

Unless there is something wrong with your tick count timing system, which I haven't validated.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my repro code is not correct. While the original code does not have this problem (wrong copy direction flag), it's very similar in nature to the one I posted. Let me re-run the fixed code again and see if it reproduces the problem.

Comment: I've updated the code and re-ran it on machines with both old and new drivers. On machine with new drivers I had the crash while on machine with old driver - no crash. I attached the debugger to the crashing application and from the call stack it looks some kind of stack overflow going on.